# GET 500 (Internal Server Error) when trying to access api

Tags: api, http, websocket, socket.io, get

I am building an application of a live news feed where I used newsfilter.io API. They have a socket server and all you have to do is connect a socket.io client to it. I had the live news feed working perfectly fine and all of a sudden I started getting the error.

NOTE: I am able to have the news feed functioning in INCOGNITO MODE on localhost:3000 but it does not work when on regular browsing localhost: 3000

[image]

My code is the same as it was before when the news feed was functioning. I have tried resetting my router several times, cleared cache/cookies, and checked for errors in my code. **The application works perfectly fine on incognito but is not working on regular browsing**

Proxy error: Could not proxy request /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NOnTLaS from localhost:3000 to http://127.0.0.1:3001 (ECONNREFUSED).

[image]

**This is the code that newsfilter.io gives to connect to their server. This code was working perfectly before as stated above but then I started getting network errors. I am using socket.io version 2.0.4 as that is required for this API**